# Include sigma in polyfit- python

Tags: python, function, numpy, linear-regression

I have 3 arrays. One array contains x-values, the second array contains y-values, and the third array contains values for sigma (errors).

How can I use the `numpy.polyfit` function to fit for x, y, and sigma? I have figured out how to fit the x and y values but not sigma.

```
import numpy as np
p = np.polyfit(x,y,2)
xp = np.linspace(0.4,1,40)
y = np.polyval(p,xp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `w` parameter as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

```
p = np.polyfit(x,y,2,w=1/sigma)
```